# Getting block information

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I need to count li elements on the website page. Elements are visible and not in frame.

html code is:

```
<ul class='uiList _10-2x _6kg'>
<li class='_10-5x'>...</li>
<li class=''>...</li>
```

end etc.

I tried to find elements using next ways:

```
xpath: count=len(browser.find_elements.by_xpath("//ul[@class='uiList _10-2x _6kg']/li"))
```

It works, but I got nothing - [ ] (without len) and 0 with len

class_name:

```
browser.find_element_by_class_name("uiList _10-2x _6kg")
count = browser.find_elements_by_tag_name('li')
len(count)
```

Here - couldn't find class name

Using li class:

```
len(browser.find_elements_by_class('_10-5x')
```

Empty result - [ ] Same as Xpath

css_selector: Selector isn't permament and changes from page refreshing.

Am I mistaken? Or are there any other ways to do it?

Comment: Can you show what the full xpath to a real desired element actually **is** according to your browser debug mode (press F12 key in Firefox or Chrome and it will start debug mode)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per provided piece of `HTML` code I see no `ul` with `class="ul class"`, but `ul` with `class="uiList _10-2x _6kg"`

You can try to specify exact class name value:

```
len(browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('ul.uiList._10-2x._6kg>li'))
```

or by partial class name:

```
len(browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//ul[starts-with(@class,"uiList")]/li'))
```

Also note that target list could be generated dynamically, so you can add some [explicit wait](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits):

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

len(wait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//ul[starts-with(@class,"uiList")]/li'))))
```